# How do I make separators for a ListView with a SimpleAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, separator

I'm new to the java programming language and I'm trying to build an app. The app has to make a list of worked hours that have been saved in an MySQL database. I found an example app, that helped me retrieving the data from the database and putting it in a ListView. 
But now we get to my problem. I want to put separators in the listview.

Now, the date of the worked hours is in every item of the ListView. I want the date only above the first item.

I've searched the internet for a way to do this, but it didn't help me.

This it the code that gets the data and puts it in a ListView:

```
    public class AllUrenActivity extends ListActivity {
    String url_all_uren;
    String ip;
    String proid;
    String uid = MainScreenActivity.uid;
    String datum;
    String datum1;
    ImageView btntoevoegen;
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;


    TextView tvDatum;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>urenList;

    // JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_UREN = "uren";
private static final String TAG_TRID = "trid";
private static final String TAG_PROID = "proid";
private static final String TAG_WERKZAAMHEID = "werkzaamheid";
private static final String TAG_TIJD = "tijd";
private static final String TAG_DATUM = "datum";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray uren = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_uren);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("databaseIP", 0);
    ip = settings.getString("ip", "").toString();
    url_all_uren = ("http://"+ip+"/android_connect/get_all_uren.php");


    // Hashmap for ListView
    urenList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllUren().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();


    // on selecting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String proid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvProid)).getText()
                    .toString();
            String werkzaamheid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvWerkzaamheid)).getText()
                    .toString();
            String trid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTrid)).getText()
                    .toString();
            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    AllProjectsActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PROID, proid);
            in.putExtra(TAG_TRID, trid);
            in.putExtra(TAG_WERKZAAMHEID, werkzaamheid);
            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);

        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received 
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllUren extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllUrenActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Uren laden...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {




        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", uid));

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_uren, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("Uren: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                uren = json.getJSONArray(TAG_UREN);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < uren.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = uren.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String trid = c.getString(TAG_TRID);
                    String proid = c.getString(TAG_PROID);
                    String werkzaamheid = c.getString(TAG_WERKZAAMHEID);
                    String datum = c.getString(TAG_DATUM);
                    String tijd = c.getString(TAG_TIJD);


                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_TRID, trid);
                    map.put(TAG_WERKZAAMHEID, werkzaamheid);
                    map.put(TAG_PROID, proid);
                    map.put(TAG_TIJD, tijd);
                    map.put(TAG_DATUM, datum);


                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    urenList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllUrenActivity.this, urenList,
                                    R.layout.list_uren, new String[] { TAG_TRID, TAG_PROID, TAG_WERKZAAMHEID, TAG_TIJD, TAG_DATUM},
                            new int[] { R.id.tvTrid, R.id.tvProid, R.id.tvWerkzaamheid, R.id.tvTijd, R.id.tvDatum });

                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }   


        });

    }

}
     }
```

list_uren.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTrid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <!-- Name Label -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDatum"
            android:layout_width="269dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toevoegen"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTijd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"

            android:text="8:00-12:00"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvProid"
            android:layout_width="138dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"

            android:text="Project"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWerkzaamheid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:text="Werkzaamheid"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

all_uren.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Main ListView 
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What is the best way to get the date separators? Thank you.

Comment: I think you can make your own custom adapter and inside getView() method you can match the date of previous row if both are same then don't show it in new row.

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the end of list_uren.xml before closing the LinearLayout

```
    <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#666666" />
```

You can change the background to whatever you want.